# Python Netmiko to get hostname

Tags: python, python-3.x, netmiko

I was able to get device hostname with the following netmiko code.

```
>>> print(net_connect.find_prompt())
Cisco#
>>> 

>>> print(net_connect.send_command('show running-config | include hostname'))
hostname Cisco
>>>
```

Would it be possible to remove `#` and `hostname` from the output?

Desired Output

```
>>> print(net_connect.find_prompt()) <= need to do something here
Cisco
>>> 

>>> print(net_connect.send_command('sh run | i host')) <= need to do something here
Cisco
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3
Cleaner:

```
#print hotname without #
hostname = net_connect.find_prompt()[:-1]   

print(hostname)

# print output without the word "hostname"
output = net_connect.send_command('sh run | i host')

for line in output:
    if "hostname" in line:
        print(line.strip("hostname"))        
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

find_prompt by default should return you either hostnem# (privileged) or hostname> - it's the whole idea behind it. As this is just a string, you can find a way around it like:

```
output = net_connect.find_prompt()
output = output.replace('#','')
print(output )
```

or

```
output = net_connect.send_command('sh run | i host')) 
output = output.split()
hostname = output[1]
print(hostname)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use TTP which is a good method where you can parallellize the data part you want. You can use the example below.

```
from pprint import pprint
from ttp import ttp
import json
import time
                
with open("showSystemInformation.txt") as f:
   data_to_parse = f.read()

ttp_template = """
<group name="Show_System_Information">
System Name            : {{System_Name}}
System Type            : {{System_Type}} {{System_Type_2}}
System Version         : {{Version}}
System Up Time         : {{System_Uptime_Days}} days, {{System_Uptime_HR_MIN_SEC}} (hr:min:sec)
Last Saved Config      : {{Last_Saved_Config}}
Time Last Saved        : {{Last_Time_Saved_Date}} {{Last_Time_Saved_HR_MIN_SEC}}
Time Last Modified     : {{Last_Time_Modified_Date}} {{Last_Time_Modifed_HR_MIN_SEC}}
</group>
"""

parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
parser.parse()

# print result in JSON format
results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
print(results)
```

Example run:

```
[appadmin@ryugbz01 Nokia]$ python3 showSystemInformation.py
[
    {
        "Show_System_Information": {
           "Last_Saved_Config": "cf3:\\config.cfg",
              "Last_Time_Modifed_HR_MIN_SEC": "11:46:57",
            "Last_Time_Modified_Date": "2022/02/09",
            "Last_Time_Saved_Date": "2022/02/07",
            "Last_Time_Saved_HR_MIN_SEC": "15:55:39",
            "System_Name": "SR7-2",
            "System_Type": "7750",
            "System_Type_2": "SR-7",
            "System_Uptime_Days": "17",
            "System_Uptime_HR_MIN_SEC": "05:24:44.72",
            "Version": "C-16.0.R9"
        }
    }
]
```